# Why can't I create summary statistics on grouped data r?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science

So I grouped my data into three variables using this code:

```
    rate_response_groupby_year_week_equipment <- rate_response_data %>% 
                            filter(TypeOfEquip == 'VAN' |
                                 TypeOfEquip == 'REEFER' |
                                 TypeOfEquip == 'FLAT')%>%
                                 group_by(Year, MonthWeek, TypeOfEquip) %>%
                                 summarize(Lanes = n())
```

Which returns these results:

```
# A tibble: 417 x 4
# Groups:   Year, MonthWeek [139]
Year  MonthWeek TypeOfEquip  Lanes
<chr> <fct>     <chr>        <int>
1 2016  Jan_W1    FLAT            68
2 2016  Jan_W1    REEFER        1603
3 2016  Jan_W1    VAN          28302
4 2016  Jan_W2    FLAT          7602
5 2016  Jan_W2    REEFER       72184
```

I want to find the mean for the Lanes column but when I run this code:

```
    weekly_mean <- rate_response_groupby_year_week_equipment %>%
        summarize(Mean = mean(Lanes))
```

I only get an average across one of the groups and not all of them which looks like this:

```
> weekly_mean
# A tibble: 139 x 3
# Groups:   Year [?]
Year  MonthWeek   Mean
<chr> <fct>      <dbl>
1 2016  Jan_W1     9991 
2 2016  Jan_W2    72640 
3 2016  Jan_W3    10860 
4 2016  Jan_W4    10338 
5 2016  Feb_W1    13222.
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what do you want the output to be? just the mean of rate_response_groupby_year_week_equipment? why not just do `mean(rate_response_groupby_year_week_equipment$Lanes)`?

Comment: Thank you Jonny Phelps. That worked. I dont know why I was over complicating it